# How to get Manage API client access screen when using GMail API with service account

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail-api, google-oauth

I am following below link to setup Service account and use GMail API to send emails by running java code from an application.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority

But here i am unable to find out Security from the list of controls. And so unable to enter ClientID in Manage API client access screen.

Please help me to navigate properly.

Thanks

Comment: Are you an owner of a Google-hosted domain? I think that dashboard is only viewable to them.

Answer (score 1):

In order to perform what you want, you need to own a G Suite account. If you already own a G Suite account, then all you have to do is follow the steps [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en). If you do not own a G Suite account then you will have to impelement a solution without a service account, therefore you will need to follow the guide [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. I did this setup few months back (G Suite is not introduced at that time) using my free gmail account.Then i was able to successfully provide gmail scope access to the project that i created in developer console and using the service account created for that project was able to send email with java code by consuming GMail API.

Comment: But currently G Suite and Google cloud platform is introduced.And still i am able to use the project created earlier and send emails using gmail API. And observed that if i create new project for my free account then i couldn't use the SA account created for that new project for sending emails. Here my doubt is, can i use the old SA account which is asscoiated for the project created before the introduction of G Suite ? If yes, how long can it be supported and is there any expiration or limitations for using GMail API to send EMails.